# Hide the folders in the working directory that are not related to the switched branch | migrating create-react-app to nextjs

Tags: git, next.js, create-react-app

I have two branches that I jump between,
branch **A** has a folder called "**.next**", while branch **B** doesn't have that one.
When I switch to branch **B** after committing my changes on branch **A**, the folder "next" stays in my working directory, which can cause confusion and mistakes made by me.

I want when switching between branches to hide the folders in my working directory that are not related to the switched branch.

---

real story: I am migrating my current **create-react-app** into using **nextjs 14** (app router).

The way I am doing it is I've created a new branch in the same working directory called "v2.0.0". While the original current create-react-app branch is called "**main**".

When I finish moving my project to nextjs, I'll merge my v2.0.0 branch to the main branch, then I'll announce the update.

By the way, I have no idea if that's the best way of doing it.

> Info: .next is ignored in branch A, but it's related to it

Comment: When you say _"branch `A` has a folder called `.next`"_ I assume you mean `.next` is added/committed in branch `A`, is that right?

Comment: @eftshift0, actually, no. `.next` is ignored in branch A, but it's related to it

Comment: ok.... I have bad news for you. _Uncommitted_ changes do not belong into a branch... that's why when you switch between those branches, you do not see that the directory goes away.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the bad news. What are the options we have?

Comment: Not trust the presence of `.next` on the FS to know if you are on branch `A` or `B`?

Comment: @eftshift0, Not trusting if I'm doing it _the right way_ or not (the migration)